# Conn to Google Cloud SQL instance from CORE w/ proxy: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred. I CAN connect via mysql cmd

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-sql

I begin by starting goole sql  proxy by running following command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=dauntless-gate-xxxxxx:us-central1:redacted-dev=tcp:3306
```

I **SUCCESSFULLY** connect from to it from running the following commands:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=sa --password=<redacted>
```

or

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=sa --password=<redacted>
```

I attempt and fail to connect using ASP.net Core 2 w/ the follwing:

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt => 
        opt.UseSqlServer("Server=127.0.0.1:3306; User Id=sa;Password=<redacted>;"));
...
}
```

Error:

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I also try with the following and get slightly different error:

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt => 
        opt.UseSqlServer("Server=127.0.0.1; User Id=sa;Password=<redacted>;"));
...
}
```

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(string hostName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SQL Server" is the name for Microsoft's SQL server product, which is not the same as MySQL, which running on your instance. You will need to use the  [MySQL Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) to connect. Check out [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entity-framework.html) for more specific guidance for Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks, that was the exact problem! I read some inaccurate documentation stating UseSqlServer could be used on mySql as well.